# Enable (or work around) Administrative shares in Windows 8

Tags: network-shares, windows-8, shared-folders

So in using Windows 8, I've discovered that the administrative shares are disabled. There seems to be no easy way to get them re-enabled.

Is anyone aware of a work around, or solution?

I did not have this issue with Windows 7 After disabling UAC. However in Windows 8 this still doesn't work.

This is all I could find, however I am not satisfied with the information provided.

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-administrative-shares.htm

http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows_8-file_sharing-windows_administrative_shares,2-195.html

Comment: There is a work around specified in the link you included.

Comment: What other information do you want that isn't in the links you've given? Solution 3 in the first link seems exactly what you're after.

Comment: "however I am not satisfied with the information provided" You need to explain this

Comment: I was hoping that there was a non "hack" solution around this. I often re-format . install these computers and didn't want to have to enable it this way each time.

Comment: With regards to the registry entry you could always export it to a .reg file and simply import it after a reformat to save the effort of opening the registry each time but it is still just as much of a "hack" as there is no official "Enable admin shares" option anywhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable administrative shares on Vista and XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/643028/how-to-enable-administrative-shares-on-vista-and-xp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note: If the computer is part of a domain, this does not apply as the admin shares are automatically enabled upon joining.**

To enable the admin shares for computers in a HomeGroup or Workgroup, you must first ensure that File and Printer Sharing is enabled:

- In the Desktop, right-click the Network icon in the system tray and click `Open Network and Sharing Center`:

  [image: Network and Sharing Center Access]
- Click `Change advanced sharing settings` in the left hand menu:

  [image]
- Under the current profile, find the `File and printer sharing` section, and click `Turn on file and printer sharing`:

  [image]
- Click `Save Changes` and confirm the change if prompted.

**Warning - the next section involves changing the Registry. Be extremely careful as incorrect editing can result in a non-functioning system or other problems!**

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click Yes to confirm starting it as an Administrator if prompted.
- On the left hand side expand the tree along the following path:

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
- Select the `System` folder and in the right hand pane, right click, click `New` then `DWORD (32-bit) Value`.
- Set the name to `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Double-click the new entry and set the value to `1`.

  [image: LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy Setting]
- Exit the registry editor and restart the computer.

Comment: I accept your answer even though its the same as in the link, since you at lease spent the time to format it nicely.

Comment: @Graham Wager I have a Question: Can I add the specified key in registry using c#. if so, how???

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do this remotely

Comment: The restart is not needed in any version of Windows, neither in Win 8, as far as I remember.

Answer (score -2):

Your first link there has the best solution IMO. Edit the registry and add the right.

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-administrative-shares.htm

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).