# How to open a network drive using \\ipaddress\driverletter+$ in windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, shared-folders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable (or work around) Administrative shares in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/492166/enable-or-work-around-administrative-shares-in-windows-8)

I have two computers in my home both connected to a LAN through a router.

When I use `\\192.168.1.3\c$` in Run from the computer having Windows 8 installed in it, it asks me for a username and password which if correctly given, gives me full access to the C drive of the computer having IP address 192.168.1.3 with Windows 7 on it.

When I do the same from Windows 7 to a Windows 8 computer using `\\192.168.1.2\c$` I get an access is denied error even though I enter the username and password correctly.

Why am I not able to get access of a drive from a computer having windows 8 installed in it?

Comment: They are disabled by default on Windows 8 - see this: http://superuser.com/questions/492166/enable-or-work-around-administrative-shares-in-windows-8/492277#492277

Comment: @GrahamWager thanks! it worked. wouldn't it be better if you wrote this link in posting an answer instead of a comment so that I would Accept your asnwer????

Comment: I knew it'd probably be closed as a duplicate, so I'll just take the upvotes on my other answer ;)