# How to get two computers on the same LAN to connect to the c$ share of each other? (no homegroup)

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing

I'm trying to do file sharing "the old style" between two computers in my network.

I'm trying to do "Start -> Run", type in \hostname\c$ or \IPAddress\c$, log in with the user and password, and access the share.

I don't want to set specific permissions when sharing specific folders. Simply going into c$ with an admin user, which gives me access to everything.

This was working perfectly fine until I had to reinstall one of them and now it doesn't work anymore.

- Once computer is Windows 7 Ultimate, the other is Windows 8.1
- In both "Sharing Wizard" is turned off.
- In both, Firewall is off
- Both are outside a homegroup.
- In both, the username I'm using is the main user of the computer, who happens to be an administrator. It has the same password in both.
- I've tried entering the username as either just the username, or "othercomputer\username" (this wasn't necessary before). It still doesn't work.

Every single time I need to get this to work it's a matter of trial and error until it happens to work and I never know why.

Could you give me the list of things that I need to make sure are set in a certain way for this to work?

Thank you

Comment: Also see: [Enable (or work around) Administrative shares in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/492166/enable-or-work-around-administrative-shares-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 0):

try the net use command
net use [devicename|*] [\computername\sharename] *

Comment: I get: "System error 5 has occurred." "Access is denied."

Comment: Look at the security for sharing -  make sure you have something where Local users authenticate as themselves (instead of as guest)